# How to center a LinearLayout in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I would like to center a LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout but i have a problem, the margin-bottom stays attached to bottom. Here is the view :

http://nsa33.casimages.com/img/2013/03/12//130312103139937791.png

And here is the code of the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/group_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/white"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/carreGlobalInterieur"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:background="@color/grisTresClair" >

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@drawable/border_deals"
                 android:orientation="vertical" >

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/GroupLigneOne"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

                         <LinearLayout
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:background="@color/grisClair"
                             android:orientation="vertical" >

                             <TextView
                                 android:id="@+id/CategorieDeal"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                 android:text="My Category"
                                 android:textColor="@color/white" />

                         </LinearLayout>

                         <LinearLayout
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                             <TextView
                                 android:id="@+id/nouveauPrixVert"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:text="10.99 €"
                                 android:textColor="@color/green"
                                 android:textStyle="bold" />

                             <TextView
                                 android:id="@+id/ancienPrixRouge"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                 android:layout_marginRight="6dp"

                                 android:text="20.90 €"
                                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                 android:textColor="@color/red"
                                 android:textSize="13sp"
                                 android:textStyle="bold" />

                             <TextView
                                 android:id="@+id/reductionPrix"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_marginRight="4dp"

                                 android:text="(-34%)"
                                 android:textColor="@color/red"
                                 android:textStyle="bold" />

                         </LinearLayout>

                     </RelativeLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:id="@+id/ligneTwo"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                     android:orientation="vertical" >

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/titreEnGros"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_gravity="center"
                         android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                         android:text="Here is an example of a compleete title in a TextView Android"
                         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                         android:textColor="@color/black"
                         android:textSize="16sp" />

                 </LinearLayout>

                 <RelativeLayout
                     android:id="@+id/ligneFour"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                     android:orientation="vertical" >

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/dateAjout"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                         android:text="il y a 2 heures" />

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/siteWeb"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                         android:text="Amazon" />

                 </RelativeLayout>

             </LinearLayout>

         </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have some ideas to center the block, please help me !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When using the `RelativeLayout`, you can use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, which will do what it says, center it inside its parent.

Comment: The centered LinearLayout also needs layout_height="wrap_content"